# FastStone Capture analog for mac

Tags: mac, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Take a screen shot of a scrolling window that includes off-screen parts](https://superuser.com/questions/39988/take-a-screen-shot-of-a-scrolling-window-that-includes-off-screen-parts)

I search for the app, that captures current window content, by scrolling it's content.

The only app, that can do this, is FastStone Capture.

Do you know such apps for the Mac ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you already looked at [AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/desktop/faststone-capture/?platform=mac&sort=likes)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/39988/take-a-screen-shot-of-a-scrolling-window-that-includes-off-screen-parts) - there are a number of options listed in the accepted answer.

If you're only looking to capture web pages, go with Little Snapper.